# Como hacer de una relación, solo un valor, Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy desarrollando un api, en la cual requiero hacer una relación pero como resultado no quiero me devuelva un objeto sino el valor en si mismo, por ejemplo, esto es lo que estoy recibiendo.

```
    {
        "id": "78",
        "fechaCaptura": "2021-06-01T10:57:39.000000Z",
        "expediente": "asd",
        "persona": {
            "id": 1,
            "fecha_captura": "2021-05-28 15:23:18",
            "nombres": "jose",
            "primerApellido": "ramirez",
            "puesto": {
                "idPuesto": 2,
                "nombre": "Administrador",
                "nivel": "0046",
            },          
            "estatus": 0
        },        
        "causaMotivoHechos": "asd"
    }
```

Pero quiero como resultado solo el nombre del puesto para el campo puesto, tipo así

```
    {
        "id": "78",
        "fechaCaptura": "2021-06-01T10:57:39.000000Z",
        "expediente": "asd",
        "personal": {
            "idPersona": 1,
            "fecha_captura": "2021-05-28 15:23:18",
            "nombres": "jose",
            "primerApellido": "ramirez",
            "puesto": "Administrador",
            "estatus": 0
        },        
        "causaMotivoHechos": "asd"
    }
```

Ahorita cuento con esto para el modelo principal

```
public function Personal()
{
$sub = $this->belongsTo('App\Personas', 'idPersona', 'id' )
->with("puesto");
}
```

y este para llamar a personas

```
public function puesto()
    {
        $sub = $this->belongsTo('App\Puestos', 'puesto', 'idPuesto');
        return $sub;
    }
```

Comment: Bueno, podría irme a hacer join regular, pero siento que perdería el sentido de usar el ORM. También me parecería mas complicado, aquí solo puse un bloque de todo, si es bastante, retrabajaría un tanto

Comment: puedes hacer un join en la relación o usar un resource, ambas te sirven en este caso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No entiendo bien tus relaciones. Por ejemplo, una persona debiese tener un `idPuesto` y mediante ese campo relacionarse con `puesto.id`.

```
public function puesto()
{
    $sub = $this->belongsTo('App\Puestos', 'idPuesto');
    return $sub;
}
```

Sin embargo en el resultado que obtienes hoy, es el modelo `Puesto` el que  tiene un campo `idPuesto`. No me cuadra.

Lo mismo con el personal. Lo lógico sería que un registro que se atribuye a una persona tuviese un `idPersona`, pero en tu ejemplo el `idPersona` está en la entidad referenciada.

Como sea, todo modelo puede llevarse a un Array, y Array Muerto Array Puesto.

Lo importante es que, lo que quieres hacer, **suele implementarse mediante accesores**. En este caso, en el modelo `Personas`

```
public function getPuestoAttribute() {
      return array_key_exists('puesto', $this->relations)?
             $this->relations['puesto']['nombre']
             null;
}
```

no sé tu versión de PHP. En versiones modernas se puede escribir más intuitivamente como:

```
public function getPuestoAttribute() {
      return $this->relations['puesto']['nombre'] ?? null;
}
```

(Yo le puse NULL, a lo mejor prefieres poner `N/A`)

Lo que está ocurriendo ahí es:

1. Se usa una convención de accesor. `getPuestoAttribute` se pasa a snake_case, quedando `get_puesto_attribute`. Quitando el get y el attribute, Eloquent sabe que queremos definir el valor del atributo `puesto`.
2. `puesto` estará definido si se pide el modelo con eagerLoading  (como `$persona->puesto`), e indefinido en caso contrario. Habrá que checkear si entre las relaciones precargadas hay un campo `puesto`.

Es un poco confuso que Eloquent te permita definir un accesor sobre una propiedad que el modelo, en ciertos escenarios, ya tiene, porque pareciera producirse una paradoja.

Antes del accesor

```
 $persona->puesto = <instancia de App\Puestos>
```

Y después:

```
 $persona->puesto = 'Admistrador'
```

Si el accesor pisa el puesto, éste ya no será un objeto ni un array.

Pero, si te fijas, en el accesor no puse

```
   return $this->puesto['nombre']
```

Sino

```
   return $this->relations['puesto']['nombre']
```

La manera correcta de plantear un accesor revisa los `attributes` o bien las `relations`. Éstos no van a cambiar aunque un accesor reemplace lo que el modelo finalmente mostrará.

Comment: Tal vez no mo entendiste por que en realidad no me expliqué bien yo, le quité muchas cosas al código para que fuera mas sencillo de leer, una disculpa XD.
La cosa es que el campo de tabla personal se llama puesto y cuando uso getPuestoAttribute() el puesto atributo si me toma el nombre para el api pero en el sistema adm que alimenta el api, requiero el ID ):

Comment: entonces getIdAttribute, y donde puse "nombre" tú pones "id"